# Global name v is not defined (but it actually is)? tkinter/python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I keep getting this error "global name v is not defined."  I know this has most likely been heavily documented, however none of the other threads were very relavant to my GUI situation.  Anyway, here we go:

```
v_amount= 5000

def set_v_to_something_else():
    global v
    v_amount=v_amount-1000
    v.set(v_amount)

v = StringVar()
v.set(str(v_amount))

#create button that will allow v label to be set to something else

vbutton = Button(root, text = "change v", command = set_v_to_something_else).pack()
vlabel = Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()
```

Once again, it says that v is not defined, even though i set it equal to StringVar()

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try defining the function *after* you define `v`.  I think that `global` looks for the variable name when you use it, not when the function is called.

Comment: @SethMMorton: No, it won't look up the name until you call it.

Comment: Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: The code you posted will not give the error you say it does. Can you include the complete stack trace in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are getting the error

```
global name v_amount is not defined
```

That would be because, in this code,

```
v_amount= 5000

def set_v_to_something_else():
    global v
    v_amount=v_amount-1000
    v.set(v_amount)
```

when Python parses the function `set_v_to_something_else`, it marks `v_amount` as a **local variable** because it appears on the left-hand side of an assignment:

```
v_amount=v_amount-1000
```

Later, when the function is called, since Python regards `v_amount` as a local variable, it tries to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment statement first and finds `v_amount` is not defined. (Remember, it is looking for it in the local namespace, not the global namespace.)

The fix is to add `global v_amount` inside the function:

```
def set_v_to_something_else():
    global v_amount
    v_amount = v_amount-1000
    v.set(v_amount)
```

You can also remove

```
global v
```

because you are not assigning a new value to `v`. `v.set` is merely calling a method of `v`.

Answer (score 0):

```
v_amount= 5000

# you need to define variable 'v' here, 
# before you define function that uses it

def set_v_to_something_else():
    global v
    v_amount=v_amount-1000
    v.set(v_amount)

v = StringVar()
v.set(str(v_amount))

#create button that will allow v label to be set to something else

vbutton = Button(root, text = "change v", command = set_v_to_something_else).pack()
vlabel = Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()
```

Comment: No, you don't need to define v before defining a function that uses v.

Comment: @user2556952: there simply must be more code than you're showing us, or you're getting a different error than you're telling us. The code you posted does not give the error you say it does, so it's not surprising that this code does not give the error either.

Comment: @BryanOakley I guessed that. :) So, I added solution for most common mistake (when def. of global value doesn't happen at a time when function is called).